# How avoid Screen name from Drawer react native navigation drawer without clickable button

Tags: android, ios, react-native, scrollview, react-native-drawer

I'm trying to remove a item from the Navigation Drawer.
I got that solution but the problem when i open drawer after my labels there is a long blank space and it is scrollable.

here my code

```
       <Drawer.Screen name="abc" component={abc}
          options={{
                title: null,
                drawerIcon: () => null,
                drawerLabel: () => null,
              }}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `contentContainerStyle` inside   `<DrawerContentScrollView>`

set drawer height constant  will fix this problem

here is the code:-

```
<DrawerContentScrollView {...props}contentContainerStyle={{height:hp('80%')}}>
```